# Commuting hash and encryption function?

Tags: encryption, hash, commutative-encryption

I wonder if there are secure cryptographic hash function $H$ and encryption function $E$ such that: $H(E(m)) = E(H(m))$ for all $m$.

Do such functions exist?

Comment: I think all hash functions that behave like a random function would already have to be discarded because $D(H(E(m))) \neq H(m)$ for those functions, the decryption of a random value will of course have a random result. But maybe there is something with a *keyed* hash that uses the same underlying block cipher or something based on number theory, I'm not sure.

Comment: Define ‘secure cryptographic hash function’?

Comment: one way, collision resistant, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **NO**

especially for all $m$

as a secure hash function generate significant different output for even a small change in $m$. (see ***Random Oracle Model*** for further references).

therefore
\begin{equation}
m \neq E(m)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
H(m) \neq H(E(m))
\end{equation}

now a hash function is not same as encryption function.

therefore

\begin{equation}
m \neq H(m)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E(m) \neq E(H(m))
\end{equation}

now from above equations, you can see it is only possible if $H() = E()$ but it is not plausible as

Hash function must be irreversible and producing a fixed length output where

Encryption function must be reversible and variable length output.

so it is not possible to exist even a single function obeying such criteria.

Comment: well, if m != E(m) it may be that h(m) = h(E(m)). the hash is collision resistant, but maybe if you choose the encryption function right, the encryption of a message generates a collision on purpose. so that's where I think it may be wrong.

Comment: 1. if the whole purpose of the encryption algorithm $E$ is to produce collision and the hash function $H$ is not collision resistant as well then $h(m) = h(E(m))$ is possible, still, $E$ should be called as collision function and not encryption because key $k$ changes output of encryption which is essential part of encryption algo. 

2. Check the length of the output of both functions. $H$ produces fixed length and $E$ produces variable length output

Comment: Could you elaborate your reasoning a bit more. You never mention the actual equation from the OP that you wish to disprove.